# Automated code generation with Enterprise Architect via COM-Interface

Tags: architecture, code-generation, enterprise-architect

I have a large set of classes in my Enterprise Architect design model from which I want to generate source code. The goal is to keep the source code consistent with the design model.

So far, I trigger the source code generation manually from the tool.
Is there a way to trigger the source code generation via the Enterprise Architect object model?
In this case, I could integrate source code generation into our CI pipeline.

Comment: See the help: projectInterface.GeneratePackage (string PackageGUID,
string ExtraOptions)

Comment: https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/automation/project_2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods

```
EA.Project.GenerateClass(string ElementGUID, string ExtraOptions)
```

or

```
EA.Project.GeneratePackage(string PackageGUID,string ExtraOptions)
```

To generate code from your model. This is documented in the [manual](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/automation/project_2.html)

Unfortunately EA can't really be used in a headless mode. You need a user with a valid license to use the API.

But on the other hand, the code won't change unless the model is changed, and the model cannot be changed unless a user is using EA.

This means that you could build an add-in that detects when the model has changed, and automatically generates the code needed. This will ensure your code always corresponds to your model.